# Trying to create a function to search for a word in a string

Tags: python, function

it's my first time posting but I have a question regarding trying to create a function in python that will search a list of strings and return any words that I am looking for. Here is what I have so far:

```
def search_words(data, search_words):
    keep = []
    for data in data:
        if data in search_words:
           keep.append(data)
    return keep
```

Here is the data I am searching through and the words I am trying to find:

```
data = ['SHOP earnings for Q1 are up 5%',
        'Subscriptions at SHOP have risen to all-time highs, boosting sales',
        "Got a new Mazda, VROOM VROOM Y'ALL",
        'I hate getting up at 8am FOR A STUPID ZOOM MEETING',
         'TSLA execs hint at a decline in earnings following a capital expansion program']
words = ['earnings', 'sales']
```

Upon doing `print(search_words(data=data, search_words=words))` my list (`keep`) returns empty brackets [ ] and I am unsure of how to fix the issue. I know that searching for a word in a string is different than looking for a number in a list but I cannot figure out to modify my code to account for that. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you explain `for data in data:`  ?

Comment: I should preface this with saying I'm very much a beginner in python so please explain it to me if I am understanding this wrong, but the way I understand it is that the for loop for data in data: says that its going to look for data in whatever data = ( ) and if search_words is in the data then it will return those strings with the search_words in it. sorry if this doesn't make sense as I'm still learning.

Comment: What is the expected output for the example?

Comment: the expected output is ['ZOOM earnings for Q1 are up 5%', 'Subscriptions at ZOOM have risen to all-time highs, boosting sales', 'ZOOM execs hint at a decline in earnings following a capital expansion program'] as those are the only strings that contain 'earnings' or 'sales'

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following. This will keep all the sentences in `data` that contain at least one of the `words`:

```
keep = [s for s in data if any(w in s for w in words)]
```

Comment: Great answer, though it’d be great if it had the non-list comprehension version too :)

Answer (score 1):

Since they are all strings, instead of looping over them all just combine them all and search that. Also make `words` a `set`:

```
[word for word in ' '.join(data).split() if word in words]
```

Using regex:

```
re.findall('|'.join(words), ''.join(data))
```

---

```
['earnings', 'sales', 'earnings']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following. This will keep all the sentences in data that contain at least one or both of the words:
This is a form of programs for beginners.
data, search_words must be a list.

```
def search_words(data, search_words):
     keep = []
     for dt in data:
         for sw in search_words:
             if sw in dt:
                 keep.append(dt)
     return keep
```